# Working with text files in c#

Tags: c#

I have a new task I want to store every student data in a separate text file..

```
id    name      subject    marks  toal subjects
1     jhone       math     60            3
2     smith       science  50            3
3     clark       math     90            3
1     jhone       science  80            3
3     clark       science  56            3
1     jhone       ecnomics 75            3
2     smith       math     40            3
3     clark       ecnomics 99            3
```

like this: filename = `1 jhone`

and data in file is

```
1     jhone       math     60           3 
1     jhone       science  80           3
1     jhone       ecnomics 75           3
```

2nd filename = `2 smith`

and data in file is

```
2     smith       science  50             3
2     smith       math     40             3
```

3rd filename = `3 clark`

and data is

```
3     clark       math     90            3
3     clark       science  56            3
3     clark       ecnomics 99            3
```

Now what I want when total subject = total records then result store in a another text

file name is `finalResult` like this

```
1,jhone,math 60,science 80,ecnomics 75
3,clark,math 90,science 56,ecnomics 99
```

and both files name = `1 jhone` and filename = `3 clark` both are automatically deleted

Comment: So how far have you got? Presumably this is homework?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: In case you don't know how, click the arrow on the upper left of the answer you want to accept. Please go back and do this for your past questions as well - if you don't care about the answers, we shouldn't care about your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice you to save it on HD as XML text file.

I think you are using C#:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement xmlStudent = xml .CreateElement("Student");
xmlmetaData.AppendChild(xmlStudent);

XmlElement xmlFirstTagElement = xml.CreateElement("FirstTag");
xmlFirstTagElement .InnerText = "YOUR VALUE";
xmlStudent .AppendChild(xmlFirstTagElement);

//SAVE ON DISK
xml.Save("Path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use: [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) to get the files, use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) to read all the lines into a string[], the [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to split the lines...